# Button onclick event is calling the page load of the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, buttonclick, pageload

I have a asp.net page where I have a button:

```
<td align="center"><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCertify" Text="Certify" 
OnClick="btnCertify_Onclick"/></td>
```

and when I click on btnCertify, the breakpoint set on PageLoad is triggered, not the breakpoint on `protected void btnCertify_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)`

How can I get the code to stop calling pageload event when btnCertify is clicked?

Comment: You can't.  Every HTTP request loads the page.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472

Comment: Both will be triggered. You can use `IsPostBack` on your `Page_Load`

Answer (score 3):

You have to add this to your `Page_Load()` event so that not all of the code executes if it is only a post-back.

```
if (!IsPostBack){
  //Your page load code here...
}
```

Comment: I have an !IsPostBack already on the page. It then falls to the else block.

Comment: Oh, well then you are SOL. Maybe you can handle whatever the `btnCertify` does on the client side instead? that will avoid the page_load...

Comment: +1 for being honest. Wish I could use that phrase and send it back to the Q/A